# How to log in to my website from specific IP address?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've just started using MVC5 and I want to make my website available just for a specific IP address, so I check the client IP address using the following:

```
Request.UserHostAddress;
```

I have two users to access to my website and every one have to access from specific IP address, so I need your help to know how to do this note that I use the default user authentication from MVC.

Every single support word is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to configure IIS or the hosting platform to restrict access, rather than a code based solution?

Comment: Agreed with Brendan; IIS, Windows Firewall, perimeter firewall, any number of other solutions are better suited to this than trying to do it in code.